# Python version mismatch even though CMake reports having found the correct version

Tags: python, c++, cmake, pybind11

I'm building some C++ Python extensions for Python 3.10 (using PyBind11) but I'm finding that when trying to import these extensions I get: `ImportError: Python version mismatch: module was compiled for Python 3.8, but the interpreter version is incompatible: 3.10.5`.

I have `find_package(Python3 3.10 REQUIRED)` in my `CMakeLists.txt` and I use `-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=$(which python)` when running `cmake`. I can confirm that `which python` points to a Python 3.10 executable. When running `cmake` part of the output says:

```
Found Python3: /PATH/TO/venv/bin/python3 (found suitable version "3.10.5", minimum required is "3.10") found components: Interpreter
```

and there are no other mentions of finding some other Python version. The compiled files look like `module.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`. Because of the `310` they can only be imported into a Python 3.10 interpreter sesion.

BUT, when I try importing them I get the `ImportError` I mentioned above. On the other hand, if I manually rename the compiled files to `module.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` and open up a Python 3.8 interpreter, I'm able to import.

How can I fix this? Why are all the clues suggesting that I have built the files correctly when I somehow haven't?

Note that I have already tried the solutions from the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62773837/cmake-and-pybind11-using-inconsistent-python-versions).

Comment: As far as I understand from the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPython.html), just `find_package(Python3 3.10 REQUIRED)` is not sufficient for create Python **modules**. These modules require **linking** with Python **libraries**, which are detected only when `Development` component is specified. Probably, you have `find_package(pybind11)` somewhere in your code. Make sure that call comes **after** the `find_package(Python3)`. Also you could check that `find_package(pybind11)` detects libraries of correct version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may have been other factors at play here (like including 3rd party CMake projects) so to fix my problem the first step was to remove those. Then I:

- changed my `find_package(Python3 3.10 REQUIRED)` to `find_package(Python3 3.10 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Interpreter Development)` (see [here](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/issues/3996)). User @Tsyvarev also somewhat alluded to this in his comment on my question.
- installed `sudo apt install python3.10-dev` (I only had this for Python 3.8). If you're like me and don't understand the difference between `sudo apt install python` and `sudo apt install python-dev` see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31002176/4391249).